# how do i convert string numbers to int

Tags: c#

I want just numbers.

```
string str_a = "a1bc2d23ghj2";
int in_b = convert.toint32(str_a); // doesn't works
```

I want the output of  in_b  to be: 12232

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string str_a = "a1bc2d23ghj2";
string str_digits_only = new String(str_a.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
int in_b = Convert.ToInt32(str_digits_only);
```

Comment: Your original post didn't compile, I edited your answer to fix it.

Comment: Use String.Join to turn str_digits_only from an array into a string. I like the .Where stuff, makes it very concise.

Comment: If you want to write even slimmer code you can just use `.Where(char.IsDigit)` instead of `.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))` since char.IsDigit already matches `Func<char,bool>`.

Comment: Thx for the solution, i wrote it like Matt said, fixed it like driis fixed and shorten it like Albin suggested. So i guess there isn't anything in .NET that would do that with 1 word.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in str_a)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        builder.Append(c);
    }
}

int in_b = Int32.Parse(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the input string is not a valid number and also because you have to use `Convert.ToInt32(string)` or `int.Parse(string)`.

If you want to extract only the numbers from a string you could use LINQ:

```
string onlyNumbers = (from ch in str_a
                     where char.IsDigit(ch)
                     select ch.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

int in_b = int.Parse(onlyNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this would be to check the char codes of the characters in your string. Select all numbers and convert them:

```
   var str_a = "a1bc2d23ghj2";
   var in_b = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join(string.Empty,str_a.Where(x => x >= 48 && x <= 57)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = Convert.ToInt(System.Text.Regex.Replace(stra, "[^0-9]", string.Empty));
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [tryparse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method.

Comment: -1: That doesn't work, there is no way to parse the number in its initial form without more work than a pure method call in .NET will give you. TryParse will just say "can't parse it", instead of throwing an exception, he still won't get the number out.

Comment: `int.TryParse(string)` method will fail too because the input string is not in the correct format.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't read the original post closely enough.